# How to overcome type safety warning without ignoring it in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, casting

I am getting warning from eclipse

`Type safety: The expression of type TreeItem[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to TreeItem<AppleItem>[]`

while using this:

```
TreeItem<AppleItem>[] friends = item.getChildren().toArray(new TreeItem[0]);
```

I dont want to use `@uncheck` or I dont want to use a loop for inserting one by one. Is there a way to do this?

Appearantly `getChildren` returns an `ArrayList` like `ArrayList<TreeItem<AppleItem>>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think so, but I wanna be sure, if you think that you are absolutely sure, u should post it as an answer so I Accept it. ty btw

Comment: Arrays and generics don't mix very well in Java, thus it's best to avoid using arrays of objects when you can. Do you really need an array? Can't you keep using the ArrayList?

Comment: actually dat ArrayList is an Observable type, so I have to use it, but ty for offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there's no way to do it without an unchecked cast. @Ivaylo's solution won't save you from casting, either.